# What happen If I build a SPA and user turn off JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, single-page-application

What would happen if i have a SPA (Single page application) with the server sending information, and the user turns off javascript? Does it would continue working or it would stop?

Comment: You mean the user turns off JS after they have already loaded the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not work.
It would completely stop working and It would show something like this.
[image]

This is the image of my localhost which I create on React.

and this is the example of udemy
[image]
UI components mounted but I can't click anywhere It's disabled.
If you want to try it on your application. then disable javascript on different website and check.
https://www.enablejavascript.io/en#chrome

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, one of the **major features of SPA is making async calls to get data** and update a part of the page.
In case you don't use JS or **disable JS, making async calls is not possible** and therefore, your SPA will no more be called SPA.